# What does "he" refer to in "He allows Lou to beat him up..."?

Tags: meaning, relative-pronouns

Here word "he" referring to whom: narrator or Joon Kim?

> With the narrator, he holds a college dropout (Joon Kim) at gunpoint
>   and  threatens to kill him if he doesn't pursue his dream of becoming
>   a veterinarian.  **He allows** Lou (Peter Iacangelo), the owner of the bar
>   where their fight club is held,  to beat him up before coughing blood
>   all over him and demanding to stay in the basement.

<sup>([Source: IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0137523/synopsis))</sup>

Answer (score 1):

The "he" in your excerpt refers to the person holding the gun.
No one else would be in a position to "allow" *something* to happen.

In this case it's Tyler, and *Fight Club* is a strange movie.